# EPPlus: Position image in a cell

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, openxml, epplus

I am trying to insert images "into" a cell in excel using Epplus.

using the following code

```
private static void SetImage(ExcelWorksheet sheet, ExcelRange cell)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("https://..."))
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
    {
        var picture = sheet.Drawings.AddPicture(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), bitmap);
        picture.From.Column = cell.Start.Column - 1;
        picture.From.Row = cell.Start.Row - 1;

        picture.To.Column = cell.Start.Column;
        picture.To.Row = cell.Start.Row;
    }
}
```

-

```
var cell = sheet.Cells[2, 2];
SetImage(sheet, cell);

cell = sheet.Cells[3, 2];
SetImage(sheet, cell);
```

However it always seems to have an overlap to the right.

[image]

If I adjust the cell widths and heights the overlap changes but never disappears

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I abandoned the

```
picture.To.Column = cell.Start.Column;
picture.To.Row = cell.Start.Row;
```

since I just could not get it to work and decided to calculated my own dimensions using:

```
picture.SetSize(width, height);
```

The trick is to understand how Excel actually calculates widths and heights.

**Height of a cell:** Its measured in points, but we want pixels. There are 72 points in an inch. One can convert points to pixel using the following formula points* (1/72.0) * DPI. DPI is dots per inch and can be found using the following method:

```
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    float dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
}
```

So to calculate the height of a cell in pixels I used

```
private static int GetHeightInPixels(ExcelRange cell)
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        float dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
        return (int)(cell.Worksheet.Row(cell.Start.Row).Height * (1 / 72.0) * dpiY);
    }
}
```

**Width of a cell:** This is a bit trickier. Basically the width of a cell in excel is equal to the number of characters (formatted using the default font) that a cell can contain horizontally.

For example

[image]

This colum is of length 12 and can contain 12 numbers in the Calibri(11) font.

That is also my excel default since my body default is calibri(11)
[image]

Here is an [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214123/description-of-how-column-widths-are-determined-in-excel) explaining it in more depth.

The next question is how on earth does one translate that to pixels.

Firstly we need to discover what the length of a character is in the default font. One could use TextRenderer.MeasureText in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. However I am using .Net Core and needed another way. Another way is to use the the System.Drawing.Common core lib which is now in preview.

```
public static float MeasureString(string s, Font font)
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

        return g.MeasureString(s, font, int.MaxValue, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Width;
    }
}
```

I then used that method to calculate the width in pixels as follows

```
private static int GetWidthInPixels(ExcelRange cell)
{
    double columnWidth = cell.Worksheet.Column(cell.Start.Column).Width;
    Font font = new Font(cell.Style.Font.Name, cell.Style.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);

    double pxBaseline = Math.Round(MeasureString("1234567890", font) / 10);

    return (int)(columnWidth * pxBaseline);
}
```

**Edit: Please note that overlap still happens when the zoom factor is set to more than 100% under display settings**

Comment: Width = number of characters in default font... that seems sad. What if your font is not a fixed width font?

Comment: Calibre is not fixed width but the numbers are so it seems to work to base your measurements on numbers?

Comment: @Murdock please have a look at this post which is similar to this post. i used your sample code but no luck for image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69115709/c-sharp-epplus-picture-height-getting-stretch-when-placed-into-cell-b1